# Why is there nothing displayed when choosing "Link to the data source by creating a linked table" option under External Data in Access?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I admit to being new to Access as my only exposure was one class on it about 3 years ago.

I'm trying to add a table from another access DB file to a destination or master file that I have. I have been able to successfully do so by using the following method:

External Data tab: Browse and selected my file with the table(s): Selected "Import tables, queries, forms, reports, macros, and modules into the current database."

That worked just fine when I clicked OK after selecting that option the tables in that file were displayed to select and add to my master file.

The problem being is that if the other database is updated then the tables in the master database are not updated. Furthermore when I select the alternative option "Link to the data source by creating a linked table" it does not show the tables that I need and displayed in the other option.

I'm open to suggestions on what could be the cause of if it is possible to add an update button to the page that would update the table based off of the other file. I just wouldn't know where to start with that and figure it would be easier to do the before mentioned if I'm doing something silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tables that appear when you choose "Import" but do not appear when you choose "Link" are themselves linked tables into yet another database. If you import a linked table from another Access database you really just copy the link (its icon is a table with an arrow pointing to it).

That is, when you import a "real" table from another database you get a local copy of that "real" table (icon is a table with no arrow). When you import a linked table you get a link to the "real" table, wherever it is, and that linked table will reflect changes to the "real" table just as if you had linked it yourself.

Comment: Gord, thanks for your response. I do see the differentiation between the real and "import/copied" icons indicated, however I guess my issue is adding the "Real/Linked" table to the database. When I select that "Link" option there is nothing displayed at all.

Comment: @JoshuaBuckley Is it possible that the other database contains only linked tables? If so, then nothing would show up when you choose "Link" because the other database has no "real" tables to link *to*.

Comment: Referencing what you just said I checked the other database and voila ! They're indeed linked tables as well. You've taught me something today and for that I'm grateful. I believe that I would just need to find the destination file that contain the "Real" tables and then it should work just fine ! Is that easy to do ? Gord I believe I just found the destination Thanks again !

Comment: You're welcome. Just remember that "Importing the linked tables from the other database" and "Linking to the 'real' tables in the other-other database" both have the same result. That is, in both cases you wind up with linked tables pointing to the "real" tables in the other-other database.